# GMLib MegaDemo.exe Won't load

Tags: gmlib

The map won't load anymore on the **megademo.exe**.
The problem start when i put: GMMap1.Active := True;

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var
  FMapLoaded: boolean;

procedure TMainForm.GMMapAfterPageLoaded(Sender: TObject;
  First: Boolean);
begin
  inherited;
  if First and not FMapLoaded then
  begin
    GMMap.DoMap;
    FMapLoaded := True;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: thanx a lot for the help =)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you must to change the method TGMMap.DocumentComplete from GMMapVCL unit with this

before

```
if (pDisp = CurDispatch) then
```

after

```
if not FDocLoaded and (pDisp = CurDispatch) then
```